# Update a field value from JS

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have created a widget to display `select` field in kanban view. I need to update a field value while change the values in `select` field.

***.js**

```
openerp.kanban_selection = function(instance){
var _t = instance.web._t,
  _lt = instance.web._lt;
  instance.web_kanban.kanbanSelection = instance.web_kanban.AbstractField.extend({

    start: function() {
      this.data = this.field.raw_value;
      this.display_selection();
      return this._super();
    },

    display_selection: function(){
      var self = this;
      console.log('inside selection');
      var select = $("<select />").html(
        $("<option />").val("monthly").html("Monthly")
      ).append(
        $("<option />").val("yearly").html("Yearly")
      ).attr({
        class: "duration_select"
      });
      self.$select = self.$el.append(select)

      select.on("change", function(){
        var l = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        params = {'val':l}
        new instance.web.Model("dashboard")
            .call("getLocations", [this,l],{context: new instance.web.CompoundContext()})
            .then(function(data) {

              self.field_manager.set_values({test: data}).done(function() {
 // here getting an error self.field_manager is undefined
              });
                console.log('data',data);
            });
      });
    }
});
  instance.web_kanban.fields_registry.add("kanbanSelection", "instance.web_kanban.kanbanSelection");
}
```

***.xml**

```
<field name="duration"  t-attf-graph_type='selection' widget='kanbanSelection'/>
<field name="test" />
```

***.py**

```
@api.one
def getLocations(self,durations):
    print'durations',durations
    data = dict(values="123")
    return json.dumps(data)
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have access to this from the kanban widget. However, I just did something similar in a form view widget. What worked for me was something like this.

Replace

```
self.field_manager.set_values({test: data}).done(function() {
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

With

```
self.view.fields.test.set_value(data);
```

I am not sure if this method returns a promise or not. I for whatever reason did not choose to do anything with a promise if one existed.

But around where you are getting your `getlocations` callback data you might want to log the self object and check to see if the `field_manager` is available. If you have issues with my suggested `self.view.fields` you may have to traverse the `self` object to see if these attributes are contained inside `self`.

```
console.log(self);
```

If you cant find the `field_manager` it may just be available through a different path.